# Possessive 's for things

Tags: possessives

> Advertising informs consumers about new products available on the
>   market. It gives us information about everything from shampoo to
>   toothpaste to computers and cars. But there is one serious problem
>   with this. The “Information” is actually very often “misinformation”.
>   It tells us the *products’ benefits* but hides their disadvantages.

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=1lEBQYDK6W0C&lpg=PA184&ots=WT9dZH6mkt&dq=%22A%20consumer%20walks%20into%20a%20store.%20He%20stands%20in%20front%20of%20hundreds%20of%22&pg=PA185#v=onepage&q=%22A%20consumer%20walks%20into%20a%20store.%20He%20stands%20in%20front%20of%20hundreds%20of%22&f=false)

According to Michael Swan in Practical English Usage:

> Unfortunately, it is not possible to give useful general rules in this
>   area: the choice of structure often depends on the particular
>   expression.

Please let me know about this particular expression: is it OK to use possessive 's with `products`?

Comment: Yes. See [Do things use apostrophe for indicating possessive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6735/do-things-use-apostrophe-for-indicating-possessive)

Comment: Yes, the products' benefits=the benefits of the products.

Comment: You could also just use "product benefits" as a [Noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct). In your example, the 's is describing properties, not possession.

Comment: Yes, of course. What research did you do before coming to ELL?

Comment: @BillJ: I saw some grammar references such as Grammar in Use.

Comment: Did those references not include non-living examples?

Comment: Sure they did. But they used categories in none of which I could put the word `product`. According to Michael Swan in Practical English Usage "unfortunately, it is not possible to give useful general rules in this area: the choice of structure often depends on the particular expression."

Comment: Mori, when you include the research you have done in the question, it makes a much better question. I **highly suggest** you include the quote from the Michael Swan book in your question. This shows that you have made an effort to answer the question on your own before posting it here. And the quote itself shows that there is some ambiguity in this area.

Comment: @AlanCarmack: "This shows that you have made an effort to answer the question on your own before posting it here." That's what I _always_ do before posting a question. "I highly suggest you include the quote from the Michael Swan book in your question." Thanks for the suggestion! Done. "And the quote itself shows that there is some ambiguity in this area." And that's why I asked native speakers here if using `products'` seemed natural to them.

Comment: Look, if a company has products and all provide benefits to the customer, you can use the plural,  no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the benefits of the product = the product's benefits.
The disadvantage of the product=the product's disadvantages

No need for plural, as it is a general statement about a product.

Comment: Actually, in this case, I think the writer is speaking about products in general, so the plural is appropriate.